# Adding text to a RichTextBox in the constructor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm creating a special kind of textbox, by inheriting from RichTextBox. I would like to be able to set the initial text in the box, which I thought I could do in the constructor as follows:

```
class SpecialTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    public SpecialTextBox()
    {
        BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen;
        AppendText("Initial Text...");
        Text += "and some more initial text.";
    }
}
```

The constructor in the above code sets the background colour, but the initial text does not appear. My question is, why doesn't the text appear, and how can I achieve this? I might want the initial text to be configurable (perhaps passed in to the constructor).

I can successfully add text later, by calling

```
specialTextBox1.AppendText("This text will appear.")
```

Why doesn't the constructor text appear?

Comment: Could you show AppendText code?

Comment: @Anton: AppendText() is part of the .NET library; it's a standard method on TextBox.

Comment: The text inside the `FlowDocument` gets overwritten later in the initialization process when the XAML for the FlowDocument is loaded.

Comment: Your code works.  The problem is the Winforms Designer is erasing what you have.  Creating the control at runtime will avoid the problem.

Comment: @LarsTech: Yes, I think you're right! The Winforms designer seems to always override the Text property, which means any constructor statements have no effect. Very annoying!

Comment: Try overriding OnCreateControl and do your initialization there.

Comment: @Siskin - answer updated for Winforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows is overwriting the text inside the `FlowDocument` when it loads the XAML for it.  This happens after the constructor for the `RichTextBox` is called.

Try adding the text a bit later, for instance in the [`Loaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event:

```
public class SpecialTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    public SpecialTextBox()
    {
        Background = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(
            System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen.A,
            System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen.R,
            System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen.G,
            System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen.B));

        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(SpecialTextBox_Loaded);
    }

    void SpecialTextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AppendText("Initial Text...");
    }
}
```

Update: you might only want to do this if the XAML that got loaded has no initial text:

```
    void SpecialTextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var range = new TextRange(Document.ContentStart, Document.ContentEnd);
        if (range.IsEmpty)
        {
            AppendText("Initial Text...");
        }
    }
```

**Update**

OK, WinForms.  WinForms sets the initial text in the c# code generated by the designer.  You should see something like this:

```
        this.richTextBox1 = new WinformsRichTextBox.SpecialTextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // richTextBox1
        // 
        this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 2);
        this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
        this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1233, 507);
        this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.richTextBox1.Text = "";
```

That last line is what defeats your constructor.  You can hack around this by overriding the `Text` method and rejecting the initial setting:

```
public class SpecialTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    bool suppressInitialSetText = true;

    public SpecialTextBox()
    {
        BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen;
        AppendText("Initial Text...");

        this.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(SpecialTextBox_VisibleChanged);
    }

    void SpecialTextBox_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Just in case, once the control becomes visible disable the kludge.
        if (Visible)
            suppressInitialSetText = false;
    }

    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!suppressInitialSetText || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || Parent != null)
                base.Text = value;
            suppressInitialSetText = false;
        }
    }
}
```

In this scheme the "Initial Text..." only appears if the "Text" line in the forms designer is empty.  Otherwise the text in the forms designer overrides the text in the constructor.

Seems sort of fragile and kludgy though.

Comment: I see where you're coming from. There isn't a loaded event for a control though (I think this event is only applicable to a Form?). Perhaps there's another similar event that RichTextBox fires... I'll have a look.

Comment: @Siskin - wait -- is this WPF or WinForms?  I've been thinking it was WPF but this may be a wrong assumption.

Comment: Ah, WinForms. Yes, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

So "Initial Text..." does not appear, but "and some more initial text." does?  At first glance, it would appear that you're clobbering the first string by assigning the second...except that you're using the += operator and not =.

I've never used the AppendText method, but I can offer some guesses:

1. Maybe AppendText doesn't work if the Text property is blank?  So the result of calling it here is nothing?
2. Maybe AppendText changes the display, but not the Text property?  So Text is still blank when you add the second string, which then updates the display to show Text?

Try commenting out the Text += ... line and see if it displays the first one.  Also put a breakpoint just before and after AppendText to see what happens to Text.

Comment: Sorry, my initial post was not quite clear. Neither of the statements in the constructor produce any text.

Comment: Oh.  Then the problem is probably not with AppendText directly, but more along dbc's lines.  It may still be interesting to see what happens to Text at each point - before, between, and after those two lines - just to make sure that there isn't something goofy going on there.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor you can set the initial text as

> base.Text = "Text what ever you want";

Comment: Hi kishore, thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't appear to work.

Comment: you have two options to solve this. 1. Instead of adding this customrichtexbox to the form at design time . add through the code by form or ulelement .controls.add(yourcontrolinstance) or    2.if you add it at design then on the properties window update the text property to your initial static text

Answer (score 1):

I added your class to a Windows Forms project and added it to a form in the `Load` event.  It seems to work as expected.  How are you added the `SpecialTextBox` to your form?

This is what my Load event looks like.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SpecialTextBox stb = new SpecialTextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(stb);
        stb.Visible = true;
    }
```

This is what the class looks like.

```
    class SpecialTextBox : System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
    {
        public SpecialTextBox()
        {
            BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.ForestGreen;
            AppendText("Initial Text...");
            Text += "and some more initial text.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the info. I'm adding the SpecialTextBox to the form using the WinForms Designer GUI, which I now think is the problem: the generated code overrides the initial text with anything I might put in the constructor.

Comment: @Siskin - yes, if you look at the source code file "Form1.Designer.cs" you will see a line like `this.richTextBox1.Text = "";`

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by the designer-generated code in the .designer.cs of your form containing your `SpecialTextBox`.

To customize that code, you can define a custom `ControlDesigner` and override `InitializeNewComponent` as followings:

```
internal class SpecialTextBoxDesigner
 : System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner
{
    public override void InitializeNewComponent(
        System.Collections.IDictionary defaultValues)
    {
        base.InitializeNewComponent(defaultValues);
        this.Control.Text = "Initial Text...";
    }
}
```

Then apply that by `DesignerAttribute` to your `SpecialTextBox`:

```
[System.ComponentModel.Designer(typeof(SpecialTextBoxDesigner))]
public partial class SpecialTextBox : RichTextBox
```

You need to add a reference to System.Designer into your project beforehand.